# Offsite payment processors

Tags: webform-civicrm, payment-processor, paypal

We require an offsite payment processor that works with webforms and can take card payments.

Paypal Express doesn't work.
Paypal standard can't take card payments with an account.

Are there any other offsite payment processes like paypal express please?

Thanks,
Andy

Drupal 7. CIVICRM 4.5.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Paypal standard should give two options. 1 to pay with your PayPal account and 2. To pay with a cc. Sometimes the cc option has a misleading label. For example it will be labeled:"don't have a PayPal account"